# Autotimestamp when check the checkbox of cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 columns , column j when I select the "NON COD" the cell is automatically checked in column K , then the column L is automatically timestamp . need help with this the app script of inserting timestamp code .

[image]

Here the code ,I try to inserting code of timestamp , but nothings happen or maybe the execution of code that helps me to run properly .

Comment: Please post code as text in the question [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "NON COD") {
    e.source.toast("Gate1")
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 11, 1, 2).setValues([["TRUE",new Date()]])
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi sir , thanks for this . yehey hahhaa